# Unit test on local SQL Server not possible due to login fail

Tags: sql-server, database, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to run unit tests in Visual Studio on a local database. The unit test project was created by another user locally on his PC and runs there successfully. I cloned his project on my machine, created the database with the same publish profile as him but when I run the tests it fails with the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'..

I made sure that the unit test project in VS can access on the database by configuring the SQL Server Test Configuration. It means it should have access to my database. For both databases we use the same user name and the same password.

Comment: As you're using the `sa` login this means that the password is either incorrect, the account is disabled on the instance, or the address for the instance in your project is wrong.

Comment: Also, the SQL Server error log will contain a message as to the specific cause of the login failure. Another possible cause is the database under test specified in the connection string is not available.

Comment: If the password would be incorrect I wouldn't be able to choose the Database from test configuration. @Larnu